# Facebook Open Graph Meta Tag

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta

I'm learning about the open graph and defining the meta properties on unique URLs but I ran into one issue that I don't understand.

I know that you need:

`<meta property="og:type" content="simonfoodapp:recipe"/>`

to define that the current page is of a `recipe` object within this Facebook app (which has a verb of `cooking` in the Open Graph settings).

---

My problem is, there doesn't seem to be any need to have `<meta> property="og:action"` within the page.

Can't you have two different actions, such as `cooking` and `studying` attributed to the object `recipe`? Or can you not have more than one verb describing the same noun?

Comment: I do not understand your question very well. Can you please try to rephrase it?

Comment: Custom open graph doesn't exists anymore

Comment: @WizKid could you explain what the custom open graph was and why it was removed? Or links to it.

Comment: Custom Open Graph stories were a way for apps to define their own actions and objects. Not possible any more, now only the pre-defined ones listed in the documentation can be used.

Comment: The question is what to do now, because our apps users needs interaction! I had everything worked, now its buggy .